# How to access data in object(stdClass) returned from query in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get data from sql query using Joomla api, when I loop through results returning from query using for each I tried to access the object properties using this:

```
$opt->id
```

I got nothing now I tried to var_dump the variable $opt and got the following

```
object(stdClass)[172]   public 'id' =&gt; string '1' (length=1)   public 'name' =&gt; string '2011' (length=4)
```

How could I access the id and name property of this object.

Thanks

Comment: How do you run the query? You need to use loadObject (or loadObjectList)

Comment: I load objects correctly and got a result as I posted above but the problem is how to access id and name property in stdClass object returned from query

Comment: It should work as you say, what happens when you try to dump it $option->id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using get_object_vars();
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php